# Predict Time of an RNN Model Output?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

I have an RNN based neural network that models a 1-1 relationship for inputs over time.

The model output is sigmoid activated, and the process I’m modeling is always monotonically increasing, so the model output for a typical example will look like a stretched/scaled sigmoid if you plot its outputs over time for a specific example.

I want to be able to predict, how long it will take for the model to hit some value if I observe some initial outputs from the model. For example, if the model is running and I observe it’s first 20 values, I want to predict how many time steps until the model crosses an output of 0.6.

I have have a set of examples of the model being run, say N examples, each with T outputs between (0,1) so my dataset is of shape (N,T,1) of historical model outputs.

I am stuck on how to use these past observations / what approach makes sense to make this prediction of time until a value is reached.